Forward Mongo Atlas Log to AWS Cloudwatch
I have a database on MongoDB Atlas and I need to forward the Atlas logs to my AWS Cloudwatch
I tried using the Atlas's Log Forwarder but it only has two options to send log to either collections or to function.
Is there any way to forward the log to cloudwatch.
